# Uniqueness Proof for Division Algorithm using Contradiction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b, \mathbb \in \mathbb {Z}$ and let there exist integers $q, q_1, r, r_1$ such that 
the two pairs $(q,r)$ and $(q_1,r_1)$ satisfy the properties:
$$\ \ \ \ a = qb+r \quad \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ; 0 \le r \lt b \\
 also, \ a = q_1 b + r_1 \quad ; 0 \le r_1 \lt b$$ 
It is assumed that $|r-r_1| \lt b$. Also, assume for the sake of contradiction that $q \neq q_1$. Then come up with another inequality involving $|r-r_1|$ that contradicts $|r-r_1| \lt b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Just follow the given hint, noting that 
$$ 0 = a -a = (q_1 - q)b + (r_1 - r) \iff r - r_1 = (q_1 - q)b $$
So $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$$\abs{r_1 - r} = \abs{q_1 - q}b$, if now $q \ne q_1$, what can you say about $\abs{r_1 -r }$?

Comment: Since $q \neq q_1$, then $r_1 \neq r$ which implies that $|r_1 - r|$ is a multiple of $|q_1-q|$ since b is an integer?

Comment: Almost. The point is that $q_1 -q$ is an integer and hence $r_1 - r$ is a multiple of b!

Comment: Ohh alright! Thanks so much for your help @martini! (: